# Selecting a particular visual studio version

Tags: visual-studio

I have a shared windows machine, I see that it has both visual studio 2019 and 2022 installed in it. But I want my build scripts to use tools like "cl" from 2019...By default it is using latest version (i.e 2022). how can I set it to use old version of visual studio (2019)? is there any setting or environment variable that I can use?

Comment: Is it an option to specify the full path to cl.exe in your built script instead of relying on the PATH environment variable?